# How to download a photo from URL and add into specific album with Objective-C for iOS8+?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I would like to download the image from this URL http://placehold.it/200x200 and add into a specific album photo on iOS.
I spent hours to work with [ALAssetsLibrary](https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum) but unable to get it working properly... Here is my code :

```
// ViewController.h
@property (strong, atomic) ALAssetsLibrary* library;

// ViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.library = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

[...]
NSURL *image_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placehold.it/200x200"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:image_url]];

void (^completion)(NSURL *, NSError *) = ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    if (error) NSLog(@"Error A : %@", [error description]);
};

void (^failure)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) return;
    NSLog(@"Error B : %@", [error description]);
};

[self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Sample album" completion:completion failure:failure];
[...]
```

Output error are :

```
Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died
Error B : Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3300 "Write failed" UserInfo=0x7ff4da570ae0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was a problem writing this asset because the write failed., NSLocalizedDescription=Write failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff4da5709d0 "Write failed"}
```

There is multiple versions of ALAssetsLibrary online but I used the last one. There is [a great tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/) about usage of ALAssetsLibrary but it's old (iOS5). Don't know if it's still supported correctly on iOS8. Can anyone help me to download an image and save it into a specific album please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 NSURL *image_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placehold.it/200x200"];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:image_url]];
 [self.library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage orientation:0 completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {}];
```

Comment: Thanks but it give me this error : `Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died`. Also in this example I can not specify a custom album.